# How to convert kWh/(m^3 multiplied by degrees celsius) to SI unit of Volumetric heat capacity?

Tags: unit-conversion

We have a project at school about making more energy efficient buildings. We are using this software called Energy3D concord. In the window where you can edit the volumetric heat capacity, the units are $\frac{kWh}{m^3 C}$ as shown in the image. I can't find these units anywhere online in any converter.

Someone please help me because all my units need to be in SI form $\frac{J}{m^3 K}$. If someone could give me a formula that I can use, it would be of great help.

Thanks in advance,

Regards,
Akhil

[image]

Comment: so i can use a converter online, using  kWh/(m³ K) without changing numbers?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I had made a mistake in my previous comment.  You have to multiply the number with $\frac{kWh}{m^3 K}$ as units with 3600000 to get the value of the quantity in $\frac{J}{m^3 K}$.

Comment: So, I'm trying to convert 0.5 kWh/(m^3 °C) and getting 1,800,000 J/(m^3 K). Is this answer correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

A kWh is a [kilowatt hour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilowatt_hour) i.e. the energy produced by a source running at 1 kilowatt for 3600 seconds. So it is 3.6 Megajoules. To convert figures in kWh/(m${}^3$ °C) to J/(m${}^3$ K) just multiply by $3.6 \times 10^6$.

Comment: So, I'm trying to convert 0.5 kWh/(m^3 °C) and getting 1,800,000  J/(m^3 K). Is this answer correct?

Comment: @Akhil: yes, that's correct.